# SoapUI how to hide password from request body

Tags: soapui, soap-client

In SoapUI (I am using 5.2.1) one of requests is login. I have to pass username and password as element values in xml. Is there a way to hide my password from being displayed as plain text in request body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to mask the password.

In order to achieve that:

- create a test case level custom property, and property name,  say `PASSWORD` then provide the value which will mask the value once you hit `return` key.
- in the request, where the value is required use `${#TestCase#PASSWORD}` if test case level property is used.
- it is also possible to define `PASSWORD` property at project level as well, so that you can avoid creating property for each test case. In that case, request should have the value `${#Project#PASSWORD}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out: The masking of the value in the UI is a feature provided by SoapUI, which just looks for certain keywords in the key field. However, the password itself is stored in plain-text in the SoapUI project file!

Comment: @SiKing It is enough because person who is standing next to you, does not see your password and it is safe to do copy-paste, so the problem is solved!